Male/Male Veela Harry Potter fan fiction
It was a Harry Potter fanfiction where Draco gets pregnant with Harry. Draco is a Veela and when Harry is born, he is one too.
I feel like Harry was mated to Ron in this one. I remember them flying on brooms to get to Ron's house and Harry is sick and dying because he did not conceive a child.
I also remember that Draco and Harry had to run down the halls of Hogwarts because the Alpha Veelas caught their scent. I remember Lucious was also trying to claim Harry because he was now a Malfoy and wanted to hand him over to the dark side.
